# nlohmann JSON, change the value of a key

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I'm using `nlohmann::json` and all I need to do is copy a JSON object and then alter some of the keys in it. Is it possible to alter keys in `nlohmann::json` objects?

Essentially what I'm trying to do is the following:

```
json obj1 = {"key with space" : 10}
json obj2(obj1);
# .change_key not a real function
obj2.change_key("key with spaces", "key_with_spaces");
```

`.change_key` is the part that I need some help on.

Comment: Yes, of course. Have you encountered a specific problem while doing so?

Comment: Use operator[].

Comment: @Quentin how do you do this?

Comment: @RickAstley can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the only way to do this is by adding and removing element:

```
json obj1 = {"key with space" : 10}
json obj2(obj1);

obj2["key with spaces"] = obj2.at("key_with_spaces");
obj2.erase("key_with_spaces");
```